# Swift UIVibrancyEffect bug while adding as subview

Tags: ios, swift, ui-design

I´am adding a Vibrancy effect view as subview. When I animate its alpha it comes to this bug:

[image: graphical Bug]

the view is in a xib with clear background and added to the blured effect view content like this:

```
let slider = Slider(nibName: "Slider", bundle: nil)
self.view.addSubview(slider)
```

It should just add the vibrancy effect to the blur view. What it does it friarly add the view with a gray background and then its drawing the vibrancy effect correctly. It should not give the user this gray from before it turns to the right effect.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is? Perhaps you could describe what is currently happening and what you expect should happen. However, bugs in iOS should be reported to Apple: https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @RoboticCat it should just add the vibrancy effect to the blur view. What it does it friarly add the view with a gray background and then its drawing the vibrancy effect correctly. It should not give the user this gray from before it turns to the right effect.